# Loading (and computing/plotting) multiple .MAT files

Tags: matlab, load

I have 4 .MAT files that I need to run similar functions on, and plot on same graph. Problem is, if I load first file, it only runs on that file. After the "load" function, there are 163 lines of code to repeat. Some answers I have seen require .Mat files with similar naming convention. 
File names are:
M1_N_o
M2_S_o
M3_N-b
M4_S_b

Answer (score 0):

Only a little info is given. If you could provide the code it will be more helpful. So I am assuming a lot of stuffs.

> I am assuming that all files have the same variables with same dimensions

First rename files

> M1_N_o.mat,M2_S_o.mat,M3_N-b.mat,M4_S_b.mat

to

> M1.mat,M2.mat,M3.mat,M4.mat

Matlab Code:

```
figure 
hold on
numberOfFiles=4;
for fileIndex =1:numberOfFiles
    fileName=strcat('M',num2str(fileIndex),'.mat');
    load(fileName);

    % your 163 lines of code

    % do your plots
end
hold off
```

If you dont want to rename the files then

```
figure 
hold on
fileNames={'M1_N_o.mat' ;'M2_S_o.mat'; 'M3_N-b.mat'; 'M4_S_b.mat'}
for fileIndex =1:size(fileNames,1)
    load(fileNames{fileIndex});

    % your 163 lines of code

    % do your plots
end
hold off
```